# Why does NANT need the .Net framework

Tags: nant

Why does nant need the .Net framework specified (in my build settings) when msbuild.exe is doing all the compile ?

Comment: Could you specify a little more details?

Comment: Nikhil Gupta, I was wondering why I need to specify the .NET version in the BUILD config file. Looking at the Nant.Exe.Config, It looks like that NANT copies default .NET libraries from folders based on which version of .Net was specified in the build file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Nant.Exe.Config, It looks like that NANT copies default .NET libraries from folders based on which version of .Net was specified in the build file.